# Location permission no longer working in iOS9.2 and Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My application had location based updates through the Significant Location Change service. It was working perfectly on previous latest iOS and Xcode releases.
I have the 'App registers for location updates' in plist.  I have the following code (pasted from different local scope from working previous app)

```
class LocationTracker: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
private let manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
override init () {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        // I do make sure SLC is available before calling this
        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
```

I do not see the prompt on iPhon6 simulator and my app has no location related items in Settings->myapp or in Settings->privacy->Location

What can I do to make it work again?

Thanks

Jitendra

Comment: Do you have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in pinfo?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I just checked, the key is there, type is String but the value is empty.

Comment: Give it a value. RequestAlwaysPermission uses it in the dialog presented to the user.

Comment: Did that, no change. Do I need an actual iPhone6, instead of iPhone6 simulator to test this?

Comment: Try resetting the privacy settings in the iPhone 6 simulator and rerun the app.

Comment: That worked. If you were to post this as an answer, I would accept it.